# Receiving an Intent when app is running in background(service app)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, background-process

I am working on an Android app which will be running on a background thread(Service app). I want to receive some data from another app through Intent(ACTION_SEND) from another app.

Is it possible for the app to receive the intent when the app is in background thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an Activity with no gui of it-s own that gets started when receiving an "ACTION_SEND intent". The activity can then inform your running background-service:

manifest

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name=".MyActionSendReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- file must have mimeType to match -->
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

public class MyActionSendReceiver extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean canWrite = SettingsImpl.init(this);

        Intent mySendIntent = getIntent();

        // TODO inform my running background service

        // no gui has been created. finish this activity
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on an Android app which will be running on a background thread(Service app).

An app does not run on a background thread. An app might *have* a background thread.

> I want to receive some data from another app through Intent(ACTION_SEND) from another app.

`ACTION_SEND` will only route to an activity of yours. Your activity is welcome to do something involving a background thread at this point. If you use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` for the activity theme and call `finish()` inside `onCreate()`, you can have the activity have no UI. So, from the user's standpoint, it appears as though `ACTION_SEND` is being processed in the background, even though this is not actually what is happening.